# Блокировка структуры

Tags: c++, многопоточность, структуры

При обращении потока к элементу структуры необходимо заблокировать структуру для других потоков. Как это сделать?

Comment: Читать msdn mutex, msdn CriticalSection, msdn semaphore.

Comment: А для *nix то же самое?

Comment: Есть же lock из стандарта! http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock или http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock

Comment: Я думаю если вы задаёте такой вопрос, может быть вам стоит прочитать какую нибудь книгу по многопоточному программированию. Т.к. прочитав про критическую сессию вы не узнаете о других аспекатах многопоточного программирования, например что такое dead-lock и как его избежать.

Comment: Согласен, уже читаю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Заблокировать структуру* не получится. А вот синхронизировать вызов методов установки/получения значения можно. Для этого используются мьютексы. Если вы используете С++11, то можете воспользоваться [std::mutex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/). Если чем-то другим, то читайте документацию этого чего-то. В Qt, например, есть классы [QMutex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html), [QReadWriteLock](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qreadwritelock.html), [QMutexLocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutexlocker.html), [QReadLocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qreadlocker.html) и [QWriteLocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwritelocker.html)

```
#include <mutex>

class A{
    mutable std::mutex _mutex;
    int _i;
public:
    inline void setI(int i){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_mutex);
        _i = i;
    }
    inline int i() const{
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_mutex);
        return _i;
    }
};
```